# Convert JSON into dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am working with Python and I have the following JSON which I need to convert to a Dataframe:

JSON:

```
{"Results": 
        {"forecast": [2.1632421537363355, 16.35421956127545], 
         "prediction_interval": ["[-114.9747272420262, 119.30121154949884]", 
                                 "[-127.10990770140964, 159.8183468239605]"], 
         "index": [{"SaleDate": 1644278400000, "OfferingGroupId": 0}, 
                   {"SaleDate": 1644364800000, "OfferingGroupId": 1}]
        }
}
```

Expected Dataframe output:

```
Forecast                 SaleDate     OfferingGroupId
2.1632421537363355       2022-02-08    0
16.35421956127545        2022-02-09    1
```

I have tried a few things but not getting anywhere close, my last attempt was:

```
string = '{"Results": {"forecast": [2.1632421537363355, 16.35421956127545], "prediction_interval": ["[-114.9747272420262, 119.30121154949884]", "[-127.10990770140964, 159.8183468239605]"], "index": [{"SaleDate": 1644278400000, "OfferingGroupId": 0}, {"SaleDate": 1644364800000, "OfferingGroupId": 1}]}}'
json_obj = json.loads(string)
df = pd.DataFrame(json_obj)
print(df)

df = pd.concat([df['Results']], axis=0)
df = pd.concat([df['forecast'], df['index'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

which resulted in an error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: Did you want to convert from unix time to datetime stamp too?

Comment: @daemon yes, which I have done in the past with this `df['SaleDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SaleDate'], unit='ms')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to create a DataFrame from the value under "Results" (this will create a column named "index") and build another DataFrame with the "index" column and `join` it back to the original DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data['Results'])
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['index'].tolist())).drop(columns=['prediction_interval', 'index'])
df['SaleDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SaleDate'], unit='ms')
```

Output:

```
    forecast   SaleDate  OfferingGroupId
0   2.163242 2022-02-08                0
1  16.354220 2022-02-09                1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very pretty but I guess you can just throw out all the nesting that makes it complicated by forcing it into an aligned tuple list and then use that:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

string = '{"Results": {"forecast": [2.1632421537363355, 16.35421956127545], "prediction_interval": ["[-114.9747272420262, 119.30121154949884]", "[-127.10990770140964, 159.8183468239605]"], "index": [{"SaleDate": 1644278400000, "OfferingGroupId": 0}, {"SaleDate": 1644364800000, "OfferingGroupId": 1}]}}'
results_dict = json.loads(string)["Results"]
results_tuples = zip(results_dict["forecast"],
                     [d["SaleDate"] for d in results_dict["index"]],
                     [d["OfferingGroupId"] for d in results_dict["index"]])
df = pd.DataFrame(results_tuples, columns=["Forecast", "SaleDate", "OfferingGroupId"])
df['SaleDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SaleDate'], unit='ms')
print(df)
>     Forecast   SaleDate  OfferingGroupId
  0   2.163242 2022-02-08                0
  1  16.354220 2022-02-09                1
```

Or the same idea but forcing it into an aligned dict format:

```
string = '{"Results": {"forecast": [2.1632421537363355, 16.35421956127545], "prediction_interval": ["[-114.9747272420262, 119.30121154949884]", "[-127.10990770140964, 159.8183468239605]"], "index": [{"SaleDate": 1644278400000, "OfferingGroupId": 0}, {"SaleDate": 1644364800000, "OfferingGroupId": 1}]}}'
results_dict = json.loads(string)["Results"]
results_dict = {"Forecast": results_dict["forecast"],
                "SaleDate": [d["SaleDate"] for d in results_dict["index"]],
                "OfferingGroupId": [d["OfferingGroupId"] for d in results_dict["index"]]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(results_dict)
df['SaleDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SaleDate'], unit='ms')
print(df)
>     Forecast   SaleDate  OfferingGroupId
  0   2.163242 2022-02-08                0
  1  16.354220 2022-02-09                1
```

Generally from my experience letting pandas read a non-intended input format and then using the pandas methods to fix it causes much more of a headache than creating a dict or tuple list format as a middle step and just read that. But that might just be personal preference.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but enke's answer was easier to understand for my simple mind :) really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Just load the `index` as a column, then use `tolist()` to export it as two columns and create a new DataFrame.  Combine the new dataframe with the original via `pd.concat()`.

In this example, I also included columns for `prediction_interval` because I figured you might want that, too.

```
d = {"Results":
        {"forecast": [2.1632421537363355, 16.35421956127545],
         "prediction_interval": ["[-114.9747272420262, 119.30121154949884]", "[-127.10990770140964, 159.8183468239605]"],
         "index": [{"SaleDate": 1644278400000, "OfferingGroupId": 0}, {"SaleDate": 1644364800000, "OfferingGroupId": 1}]
        }
}

res = pd.DataFrame(d['Results'])

sd = pd.DataFrame(res['index'].tolist())
sd['SaleDate'] = pd.to_datetime(sd['SaleDate'], unit='ms')

pi = pd.DataFrame(res['prediction_interval'].map(json.loads).tolist(), columns=['pi_start', 'pi_end'])

df = pd.concat((res, pi, sd), axis=1).drop(columns=['index', 'prediction_interval'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but enke's answer was easier to understand for my simple mind :) really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score -1):

You must use the pandas library:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
print(data)
df = pd.read_json('data.json')
df
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but enke's answer was easier to understand for my simple mind :) really appreciate your help :)

Comment: This is a copy-paste of an abandoned, then deleted answer, also it doesn't answer the question.